# My app crash when use also once <android.support.design.widget

Tags: android, android-studio, crash, android-widget, android-support-design

hi i create the sample project but crash.

I run device with kitkat but my app crash and show only the message that 
anomal error why ? i use android studio lastversione

**my build.grade** add support 22 and appcompat

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    //compile 'com.github.shell-software:fab:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
}
```

my test activity is blank activity create from android studio

**my test activity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.android.xxx.TestActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_drawer"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

### UPDATE

I found the optimal configuration

this compile and run on device and on emulator, my layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="401dp">

        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_black"
            android:layout_gravity="start|left" />



    </LinearLayout>



    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"
        />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

my script

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
//    compileSdkVersion 22
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android4dev.navigationview"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
//    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your build tools and sdk version dosen't match.

Change your build tools version to:

```
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your build tool and library versions seem old. Current version is `23.0.1`
Go to your sdk manage and update build tool and support libraries.

After updating tools change your Gradle file to use latest build tools and support libraries which is `23.0.1`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
}
```

Comment: support-v4 should also have 23.0.1 as the version and not the wildcard.

Comment: the principal line of the logcat is:

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

Comment: @BruceStackOverFlow Yes, because it's not able to find FloatingActionButton  in correct library. You have to update your libraries to use the latest one and correct versions.

Comment: OK I have modified versions as you indicated ... but does not work...as upgrade the lib ??

Comment: update...
i mod the script: <br/>
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 19
...
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'

compile at run on emulator and real device show this exception

Answer (score 0):

@Sharj

the build with ouput

```
D:\Users\robi\StudioProjects\QuandoArrivo\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.1\res\values-v23\values-v23.xml
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
```

Comment: I found the project that use the FloatingActionButton  and the Width from support.design. run on emulator and on device. Check the code and figure out where is the problem. Then review the results. other tips are always here
... [link git-hub project](https://github.com/AkashBang/NavigationView)